# Footer will not stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

[image]

The footer will not stay at the bottom of the page. I render a partial inside my application.html.erb file. I am wondering if it is because im rendering the footer partial outside the div container i have inside my application erb file.

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>

  <body>


    <%= render 'shared/navbar'  %>
    <%= render 'shared/message'  %>

    <!-- NOTIFICATIONS -->
    <% if current_user %>
    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<%= current_user.id %>">
    <% end %>



   <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

  <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>


<footer class="section footer-classic context-dark bg-image" style="background: #2d3246;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-30">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-5">
          <div class="pr-xl-4"><a class="brand" href="index.html"><img class="brand-logo-light" src="images/agency/logo-inverse-140x37.png" alt="" width="140" height="37" srcset="images/agency/logo-retina-inverse-280x74.png 2x"></a>
            <p>We are an award-winning creative agency, dedicated to the best result in web design, promotion, business consulting, and marketing.</p>
            <!-- Rights-->
            <p class="rights"><span>©  </span><span class="copyright-year">2019</span><span> </span><span style="color: red;">B</span><span>. </span><span>All Rights Reserved.</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h5>Contacts</h5>
          <dl class="contact-list">
            <dt>email:</dt>
            <dd><a href="info@budlyfe.com">info@b.com</a></dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-3">
          <h5>Links</h5>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a><%= link_to 'About', about_path %></a></li>
            <li><a><%= link_to 'FAQ', faq_path %></a></li>
            <li><a><%= link_to 'Contact', contact_path %></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 3):

What others have said using fixed positions will work. Another alternative if you don't want to take anything out of the flow is to use flex.  Just wrap everything that isn't footer in a container. Then give the body class something like

```
body{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.container{
flex-grow: 1;
}

footer{
flex-grow: 0;
}
```

So the body is at least the height of the viewport.  The footer is however tall it needs to be and the container, regardless of how much stuff is in it, will at least fill in the rest of that space forcing the footer down.  Here is a [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/Spenser_Peiffer/pen/LqZgzm?editors=0100) if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define a static height for footer and a fixed position with 0 bottom , something like this :

```
footer {
   position: fixed;
   height: XXX;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding in CSS?

Try something like this.

```
.footer-classic { 
   position: fixed;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   height: defineYourHeight;
   width:100%;
}
```